# Plot shapefile on top of raster using plot and imshow from matplotlib

Tags: python, fiona, matplotlib, geopandas, rasterio

I need to plot a shapefile on top of a raster. I would like to use the python package [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) and some combination of fiona or geopandas to load the shapefile.

I found an example in the [rasterio documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html) but it doesn't provide code for the actual plotting.

[image]

I have tried loading the raster with rasterio, loading the shapefile using fiona, calling `imshow` on the raster, and calling `plot` on the shapefile. However, the shapefile does not appear on the plot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I added that recipe to the `rasterio` documentation. Since it was such a simple shape, in this case I just unzipped the coords in the single record contained by the shapefile. That is, `x, y = zip(*features[0]['coordinates'][0])`, and then just plot.

More generally, I use `PolygonPatch` from [descartes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/descartes), and `matplotlib.collections`.

```
import fiona
import rasterio
import rasterio.plot
import matplotlib as mpl
from descartes import PolygonPatch

src = rasterio.open("tests/data/RGB.byte.tif")

with fiona.open("tests/data/box.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    features = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

rasterio.plot.show((src, 1))
ax = mpl.pyplot.gca()

patches = [PolygonPatch(feature) for feature in features]
ax.add_collection(mpl.collections.PatchCollection(patches))
```

The appearance of the shapes can be customized with keywords like `edgecolor` or `facecolor` passed to `PolygonPatch`. To produce a thick red line as in the example, replace the last two lines in the example above with:

```
patches = [PolygonPatch(feature, edgecolor="red", facecolor="none", linewidth=2) for feature in features]
ax.add_collection(mpl.collections.PatchCollection(patches, match_original=True))
```

The `match_original` keyword is necessary in the second example because parameters like `facecolor` and `edgecolor` can also be set in `PatchCollection`, and the default is to ignore settings of the passed in patches in favor of those set by `PatchCollection`. Doing so using `PolygonPatch` gives more flexibility to set different colors, widths, etc., for each patch that you add.

Comment: I am having trouble importing `rasterio.plot`. Any ideas? I am using rasterio version 0.25.

Comment: `rasterio.plot` was only recently introduced. Use `rasterio.tool` instead for older versions.

Comment: is there a prerequisite that tiff and shp file should be in the same projection?

Comment: Yes, the bounds of the raster in whatever projection it is in are used to set the extent of the plot window, which then allows the vector layer to be properly overlaid.

Comment: @jdmcbr, thanks for adding the recipe here. It would be great to add it to the original rasterio documentation, I ran into the same problem.  :)

Comment: 5 years later but I just need to stress the importance of not missing the "match_original=True" part of the answer...

Comment: is there a way to plot several maps with faceting?