# Graph points in image using matplotlib

Tags: python, shapely, matplotlib, rasterio

I am trying to plot points (latitude, longitude) inside a raster image in Python. First, I read the image using `rasterio` and plot it using the same package, after transform the image from `uint16` to Byte (`uint6`):

```
#Transform to uint8
def scale8bit(image):
    scale = float(256) / (image.max() - image.min())
    return np.clip(np.round(np.multiply(image, scale)), 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)
#Read image and plot visible bands    
src = rasterio.open(path)
array_8b = img_as_ubyte(img_as_float(src.read([3, 2, 1])))
a = scale8bit(src.read([3, 2, 1]))
```

Now, I have some WKB points which coincide --as far as I can tell from the data-- with the bounding box of the image. Hence, I am trying to run the following in order to visualize the images and the points (read using `shapely`):

```
from shapely import wkb
from rasterio import plot.show
for i, geom in zip(selected_images_paths[0:10], subset_images["geom"][0:10]):

  #Open file using rasterio and change to int8
  src = rasterio.open(i)
  src_8bit = scale8bit(src.read([3, 2, 1]))

  #Graph!
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30, 30))
  plot.show(src_8bit)

  #Open geom with shapely
  geom_wkb = wkb.loads(geom, hex = True)
  x,y = geom_wkb.xy
  ax.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o', s=50, c='r')
```

The units of the graphs are clearly on color intensity and not in long, lat, which are the units of the x,y tuple. I've tried different options, but I can figure out how to overlap both data sets.

Is there something wanting, or should I take another approach?

**EDIT**
I have been following the code described in this question ([Plot shapefile on top of raster using plot and imshow from matplotlib](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193653/plot-shapefile-on-top-of-raster-using-plot-and-imshow-from-matplotlib?rq=1)). Nonetheless, the result is sub-optimal.

When I use `ax = plt.gca()` to set the axes in the subplot, the `fig` definition is completely ignored for some images and the resulting figure is small. I think the error must be on the `ax` or `fig` definition, but I've tried other suggestions in the documentation without success.

Comment: Hi Ivan did you ever get this to work as you wanted?

Comment: Yes, it was as extension issue. The point wasn't sharing the image coordinates (as the answer describes the `pyplot.imshow` is not showing geographical axes, but color ones). I'll mark the answer as correct. Thanks for taking me back in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be multiple problems here.

On the larger problem of sharing axes or making `rasterio.plot.show` not also invoke `pyplot.show` (which renders the current figure to screen). If you look at the [rasterio docs on plotting](https://mapbox.github.io/rasterio/topics/plotting.html), you will see that `rasterio.plot.show` takes a keyword argument called `ax` which allows for specifying an existing axis. You should pass in the `ax` variable you create with `plt.subplots`.

I think you are also encountering a problem with coordinates. `rasterio.plot.show` is a wrapper around `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow`. This function plots an image in the **image space**, not the **geographic space**. That means the image does not have georeferencing as might be expected. The `transform` argument to `plot.show` just handles formatting the labels for the axes; it does not shift the location of the image in the plotting space. Therefore attempting to plot the corners of the image as longitude-latitude pairs will actually result in plotting the points as pixel coordinates. You will need to either transform the lon-lats into pixel coordinates using the inverse geotransform from the image or place the image into its proper geolocation with `pyplot.imshow(img, extent=[left, right, bottom, top])` (see an example question that is similar to yours [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999621/how-to-use-extent-in-matplotlib-pyplot-imshow)).