# How to plot a shapefile over a raster in Python

Tags: python, raster, shapefile

I am beginner to work with GIS, so be patient.

My first task is to do:

- Read a raster file   (Done)
- Create a shape file  (work on it)
- Create a new raster from the shapefile (not started)

I am having trouble with to plot the shapefile that I have created over the raster image. The bounding box do not appear at image. How can I figure this out?

I was trying to do something similar to this post: [Plot shapefile on top of raster using plot and imshow from matplotlib](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193653/plot-shapefile-on-top-of-raster-using-plot-and-imshow-from-matplotlib)

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import rasterio as rio # funcao similar ao R do raster
import rasterio.plot as show
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.collections as cplt
import fiona
import shapely
from descartes import PolygonPatch
from osgeo import gdal

# Read the raster file
filename = "C:/Users/adolf/Desktop/Annia_teste/ALF_16JUN26141551_M2AS_R02C1_pansharpen.tif"
dataset = rio.open(filename)

# Get the band, width and height from raster data
nband   = dataset.count
nwidth  = dataset.width
nheight = dataset.height

# O tipo de dado fica na propriedade .dtypes

# =============================================================================
# Dataset georeferencing #

# Item 1 -  Obtendo o valor corresponde aos vertices da imagem em metros 

bounds = dataset.bounds    # Get the spatial geopoint
matrix = dataset.transform # Get the affine matriz to relate the pixel with spatial position
crs    = dataset.crs       # Get Coordinate reference system


# =============================================================================
# Using Fiona to create the shapefile #

# Define your schema as a polygon geom with a couple of fields
schema = {
    'geometry': 'Polygon',
    'properties': OrderedDict([
        ('somecol', 'str'),
        ('anothercol', 'int')
  ])
}


# Create a set of shapefile which are construct by defining a 256 x 256 pixel 

square_size = 256
nrow = int(nheight/square_size)
ncol = int(nwidth/square_size)

nrow = 1 #bypass test
ncol = 1

with fiona.open('oo.shp', 'w', driver='ESRI Shapefile',  crs=crs, schema=schema) as c:
        
    id = 0
    for col_id in range(0,ncol):
        for row_id in range(0,nrow):
            
            #Criando o poligo a partir dos vertices
            right_bottom = matrix*(row_id*square_size,col_id*square_size)
            left_bottom  = matrix*(row_id*square_size,(col_id+1)*square_size)
            right_top    = matrix*((row_id+1)*square_size,col_id*square_size)
            left_top     = matrix*((row_id+1)*square_size,(col_id+1)*square_size)
    
            # Corrigindo a ordem p/ escrever os pontos na sequencia correta
            #lr, ur, ll, ul = zip(*polygon)
            polygon = [(right_bottom, right_top, left_top, left_bottom)]
        
            record = {
                'geometry': {'coordinates': polygon, 'type': 'Polygon'},
                'id': id,
                'properties': OrderedDict([('somecol', 'Some Value'),
                                           ('anothercol', 12345)
                                           ]),
                'type': 'Feature'}
            #Escrevendo no artigo
            c.write(record)
            id = id + 1

# Reading the shape file I have just created
with fiona.open("oo.shp", "r") as shapefile:
    features = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]


patches = [PolygonPatch(feature) for feature in features]

ax = rio.plot.show(dataset, adjust='linear')
ax.add_collection(cplt.PatchCollection(patches))
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there to pick an error in. I'm not a shapely or fiona user but I can see you're not closing the polygon, you need to specify your origin point  again as the last point to close it: *polygon = [(right_bottom, right_top, left_top, left_bottom,right_bottom)]*, though the order of vertices is counter clockwise which may also be an issue. I'm not sure about the matrix part, I think it would work just as well without matrix, as the example https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#record-geometry the coordinates are simple tuples.